# PHPUnit and WebDriver(Selenium2) - How to operate an element before the page's fully loaded?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, phpunit

By default , Webdriver always wait for a page's full loading, then find the element on this page and operate it.

e.g. open the google.com website, wait for its full loading, then find the search button ,and click it.

Sometimes, the page connects to some external link ,such as GA (statistics service), which usually takes too much time. And the button  that I want to click  has been loaded before the page's completely loaded.

How can I let Webdriver click a button  when the button  has been loaded ,when other parts of the page are still  in loading progress?

Answer (score 0):

You could always put a wait command in there.

```
 sleep(5);
```

This will make it ' sleep for 5 seconds '

Though, it's easier to use ' waitForElementPresent();

```
 $this->waitForElementPresent("YOURELEMENT","50000");
```

this will make your script wait for 50 seconds or until the element is loaded
YOURELEMENT = the locator
50000 = The timeout

Comment: hi @Decypher, your answser is not suitable for this question. I found the page load stragety of selenium,it's NORMAL ,which means selenium has to wait for the page's full loading.

Comment: When you use the waitforelementpresent , selenium will continue if the element is visible, so if the rest isn't loaded yet but your element it will. Or do you want to complete page to load? 
The page load  of selenium is whenever selenium thinks it's done, then it continues which is in some cases wrong.